# Spring MVC Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name using ModelAndView and Form tag

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, javabeans

It seems like I cannot solve this problem even though I read some questions and answers on here. I am using spring mvc and trying to make member information edit form.

This is error message.

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute
```

I am using Member.vo and It already has all getters and setters which are needed for this.

This is controller. first one is for getting member's information

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setting(HttpSession httpSession){

    String s_id = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("s_id");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("memberedit");

     if(s_id !=null){
        Member member = membermapper.memberEdit(s_id);
        mav.addObject("command", member); }

return "setting"; }
```

This one is uploading member's new information

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/membereditadd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String memberEdit(Model model, HttpSession httpSession){
        Member member = new Member();
        membermapper.editForm(member);

        String s_url = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("s_url");
        model.addAttribute("command", new Member());

        return "redirect:"+s_url;

    }
```

This is setting.jsp

```
<form action="membereditadd" commandName="command" method="post" name="form">

<label for="id">id</label>
 <form:input class="form-styling" type="text" path="id" />

 <label for="pw">password</label>
 <form:input class="form-styling" type="text" path="pw"/>

 <label for="email">e-mail</label>
 <form:input class="form-styling" type="text" path="email"/> 

        <input type="submit" class="btn-signin" value="submit">

     </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various issues here. For example you create a ModelAndView in the GET handler but then return a plain String. You need to return the ModelAndView.

I have tidied things up a bit. The following expects your JSP to be named editMember.jsp

GET Handler:

```
/**
  * Spring MVC Controller. Loads an existing Member, sets it in the Model 
  * and forwards to the edit member page.
  *
  */
@RequestMapping(value = "/editMember", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadEditMemberForm(HttpSession httpSession){

    String s_id = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("s_id");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editMember");

     if(s_id != null){
        Member member = membermapper.memberEdit(s_id);
        mav.addObject("member", member); 
      }

    return mav; 
}
```

POST Handler:

```
/**
  * Spring MVC Controller. Handles form submit. Framework will automatically
  * bind for fields with path X to Member fields named X assuming corressponding
  * setter setX() is present.
  *
  */
@RequestMapping(value = "/editMember", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editMember(ModelAttribte("member") member, HttpSession httpSession, RedirectAttributes ra){
    Member member = new Member();
    membermapper.editForm(member);

    String s_url = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("s_url");

    //if you are using a redirect 
    //then you need to use RedirectAttributes
    //this makes the Member available to next view
    ra.addFlashAttribute("member", member);

    return "redirect:"+s_url;
}
```

Updated Form. Use 'modelAttribute' instead of 'command'.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="member" method="post">

    <label for="id">id</label>
    <form:input class="form-styling" type="text" path="id" />

    <label for="pw">password</label>
    <form:input class="form-styling" type="text" path="pw"/>

    <label for="email">e-mail</label>
    <form:input class="form-styling" type="text" path="email"/> 

    <input type="submit" class="btn-signin" value="submit">
</form:form>
```